# How to encode a web-request correctly

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Over my app I call a web-service and recieve this characters

```
ad_module=https%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fswfbin%2Fplayer-vfl7UxYqE%2Fad.swf&tmi=1&sentiment=2&fexp=900718%2C907263%2C927622%2C931348%2C9406165%2C941004%2C943917%2C945049%2C947209%2C947225%2C948124%2C948528%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C955301%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201%2C957505%2C959701&iv_allow_in_place_switch=1&iv_load_policy=1&thumbnail_url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FGdbNLaAsWRQ%2Fdefault.jpg&title=New+Renault+Twingo+2014+90hp+acceleration&hl=de_DE&watch_ajax_token=QUFFLUhqblVhTlpnNUJKNVZ5RlVmbjlCX2xqRmJCWDM4UXxBQ3Jtc0tuLWZJY3pvQ21nTng1eUt3WWZwVmQyMzQ0Y0tWQjVGamZ2STZZOERla0xINDBsLWxZaUlLU190VXljUUtnLWRuTi10SEZwUWoxeFdnYU1EaFR2RXdPWFpVbGtHVllEQjJGb0Y1a19XYmx6a0xqZF9lQQ%3D%3D&allow_ratings=1&iurlmq=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FGdbNLaAsWRQ%2Fmqdefault.jpg&ldpj=-7&adsense_video_doc_id=yt_GdbNLaAsWRQ&oid=OhtdX2lS_hQJkSaAgDys-g&cos=Windows&sffb=True&account_playback_token=QUFFLUhqbEtfaWtianhZUnZQWVVDWkktdjl5ejMyd2Mtd3xBQ3Jtc0ttQlVFSVdZdUN2MHZOSDdEY0lzZVozdE5xLUdQcy1uYkpNRG5FeHJTa3pxVDUzNDNiaWRHcUp5Z2...
```

How do I have to encode that string so I will be able to make another call and recieve the data from one of the links?

I allready tried to encode to UTF-8, but that doesn't solved the problem

With this [tool](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) I could get a working result (*Unicode U+hex notation*), but I don't know what this encoding would be like in code, any ideas?

Tried this:

```
final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
text = new String(text.getBytes(UTF_8), UTF_8);
```

and this:

```
text = URLDecoder.decode(text, "UTF-8");
```

But they didn't even changed something

Do I maybe also have to change something on the reading from the web-request (input-stream,etc)?

**EDIT:** Had to decode it twice to get working url's

Comment: hello, your url is already encoded, if you meant decode the url you can use something like `String urlDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(encodedUrl, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @medhdj, see my edit, allready tried this

Comment: it's weird!, can you post the output of `decode(text, "UTF-8");` method

Comment: Had to decode it twice, then i got working url's